# Website container not containing contact form

Tags: html, css

I am rather new at coding websites and am having a little difficulty coding this website.

***Note***: I have uploaded 2 pages onto my business website to demonstrate my problem. Please don't click on the links as they will not work properly.

The home page is working fine `www.dbayliss.com/rshome.html`, but I am having trouble with the contact page `www.dbayliss.com/contact2.html`.

As can be seen the container or wrapper what ever you want to call is is not holding the content of the contact page. I have the container's height set to 100% which is working for the home page just not the contact page.

Here is the [CSS](http://pastebin.com/x5A7Qzvz).

Comment: Code should always be posted in your question, not just linked to.

Comment: @WebNoob, answered your second question. but to be honest there's too much improper with your code, do you really need so many position manipulating?

Comment: @Godinall Thanks that fixed it :) I am not sure if I need as much position manipulating, but it was how I was taught, so it's all I know. Thanks again, you've really been a big help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#contact {
width: 400px;
height: 282px; //change to 800px or more
position: absolute; //change to relative
top: 90px;
left: 150px;
color: #000;
font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
display: block;
}
```

when position set to relative, it sets the element out of your container so your container doesn't get actual height

Comment: thanks, that has put the form back in the container but has made "Name:" move position, any advice on how to put it back in place above the field? http://dbayliss.com/contact2.html

Comment: add position:absolute; to your #nav_bar {}, it's because your nav bar is taking that height and expands your first line of form field

Answer (score 1):

Removing `top: 50px;` from `style2.css` line number 25 seemed to have moved the logo into the container.  Since header is already inside container, you do not have to offset the header by the 50px.